# How to ask off-topic questions: just award a bounty

Tags: discussion, bug

Just saw this question [WooCommerce Tax Filter Not Fired](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/353107/woocommerce-tax-filter-not-fired).

It is about WooCommerce, so I quickly wanted to vote-close it as off topic but got a notice:

> This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed

Is this the desired behavior? How should we proceed in cases like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How should we proceed in cases like this?

You do exactly what you just did :)

Go go Mod powers!!

[image]

I've removed/refunded the bounty and given my own close vote, this is one of those situations were a community moderators intervention is necessary, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Thanks Tom! Personally it bugs me that WooCommerce is not supported here as there are very few programming-oriented communities about it, but that is another discussion

Comment: We tried setting up a Woo stack, but it never got enough activity to graduate to the beta stage, and there was no official support outside of sentiment/retweets

Comment: Just curious, does the OP get his bounty refunded?  I would think/hope so.

Comment: indeed they do, take a look at the users reputation tab on their profile, and their reputation graph, and you'll see it got refunded https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/178754/user1932595?tab=reputation

Comment: Between StackOverflow and WPSE, I'm suprised there wasn't enough activity for a Woo Stack on it's own... ...lately it's almost like it's every 3rd question, especially on Overflow.  How long ago was the attempt made? (Just did a quick check, filtering using the WordPress tag on SO, out of 15 questions, 8 were tagged with WooCommerce.)

Comment: @TonyDjukic there are plenty of questions, the problem was nobody was interested in answering them, you can't pass Area 51 with a stack of open questions and no answers. A lot of the regulars on this stack aren't WooCommerce experts so it was difficult to lend a helping hand, though if we had been able to it would have just flopped at the next stage if it never attracted enough mass to self-sustain

Comment: That actually makes sense;  WooCommerce is intricate and very often the use-cases are super specific, as are the problems.  I've worked with it a substantial amount but often don't even clearly get what the questions are asking. :-/  I once spent 18 hours troubleshooting a CSV export from WooCommerce because, as I learned while finally solving it, there are 8 different `-` in code and the difference between some are imperceptible to the human eye.  May also be that every WooCommerce site uses an array of varied plugins, so every set up is different and thus harder to answer questions for.